# SQLite3. Select only highest revision using FKs, MAX() and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sqlite

### What you need to know about schema and data:

```
SELECT * FROM 'income';  -- Returns all 309 rows.
SELECT * FROM 'income' WHERE businessday_revision = 0;  -- 308 rows
SELECT * FROM 'income' WHERE businessday_revision = 1;  -- 1 row
```

The businessday table has:

```
id INTEGER,
revision INTEGER,
....
PRIMARY KEY(id, revision)
```

The income table has:

```
id                    -- integer primary key, quite unimportant I think
businessday_id        -- FK
businessday_revision  -- FK, when a day is edited, a new revision is created
```

The foreign key looks like this:

```
FOREIGN KEY(businessday_id, businessday_revision) REFERENCES businessday(id, revision) ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

### The problem

I want to select incomes only from the latest revision on each day. **Which should be 308 rows.**
But sadly I'm too dense to figure it out. I've found that I can get all the latest businessday revisions using this:

```
SELECT id, MAX(revision)
FROM businessday
GROUP BY id;
```

Is there some way I can use this data to select my incomes? Something along the lines of:

```
-- Pseudo-code:
SELECT *
FROM income i
WHERE i.businessday_id = businessday.id THAT EXISTS IN
    (SELECT id, MAX(revision)
    FROM businessday
    GROUP BY id);
```

I obviously have no clue here, please point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM Income i
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT id, MAX(revision) maxrevision
        FROM businessDay
        GROUP BY id
    ) t ON i.businessday_id = t.id AND i.businessday_revision = t.maxrevision
```

Comment: Wow, I'm astonished. In mere seconds you type out working SQL to something I've spent hours on already. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about using join?

```
SELECT  i.*
FROM    income i
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  id, MAX(revision) revision
            FROM    businessday
            GROUP   BY id
        ) s ON i.businessday_id = s.id AND
                i.businessday_revision = s.revision
```